# Responsive design initial width, need advice please

Tags: responsive-design, photoshop

I've recently started to try to understand responsive web development and CSS media queries. I was given a photoshop design to convert to responsive HTML.

Here is my dilemma..the design's overall width is only 785px total. I don't think I've ever seen a RWD less than 960px wide?? Being still new to this, I don't know if this is a problem and if I should go crazy trying to make it work? The layout is a 2 column design on the home page, and the rest of the pages are 3 columns (left sidebar, wide center area for content, right sidebar) and a four column footer.

Should I go back to the designer and tell him that he needs to redo the whole thing wider? I really want to avoid doing that because he has hired other agencies to build his branding on print based on this design.

Would you work with this width? Is it do-able?

If so, I want to use a template which would be a big help for me at this point in learning. The design is as standard as it gets. No interactive elements except for hyperlinks, so nothing there that would require js or jQuery to function.

If anyone can recommend a template/framework that won't be overwhelming in features and extras for a simple project I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: This isn't a programming question...

Comment: I missed that one for sure. If I can move it I will!

Answer (score 0):

If the design can't be scaled up to 960px, then you could create your own css grid system.

Head over to: http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs04.php?GridWidth=785&GridColumns=2&GridMarginLeft=29 and take a look at the grid I just knocked up. You can also create your own there.

Remember, for your two column layout, for the total width to be 785px, the margin-left on the second column will need to be an odd number in order to create two evenly sized columns.

For the three column layout, you could use this grid system http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs04.php?GridWidth=785&GridColumns=3&GridMarginLeft=28

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and resource. I'll check out what you did in detail and report back if needed. The important fact is you confirmed this can be done at that narrow starting width.